# How to draw such (e.g. 5 by 5) a grid with thick boarders efficiently in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, drawing

In Word (or Excel or Visio or any other similar), how to quickly draw such grid?

[image]

For example, for each 5 by 5 squares, the boarder are thicker.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

•Using the drawing toolbar, choose the rectangle icon and draw a rectangular box on the worksheet.

•Right-click the box. Choose Format Autoshape. On the Size tab, change the size to 1" x 1"

•On the properties tab, change properties to "don't move and size with cells " 
•Using View - Zoom, adjust the worksheet to maximum

•Place the box to the most upper left corner (cell A1)

•Adjust row and column size of cell A1 manually until it match with size of the box

•read the row and column scale and use it to update the whole row and column.

Do This using macro and you will be fast :D

Taken from:http://www.mrexcel.com/tip071.shtml

Comment: To make the cells square the easiest way is to go into Page Layout View.  Then you can set row heights and column widths in inches/cm instead of the seemingly arbitrary system used in normal or page break view.

Answer (score 1):

For excel you you basically have to build 1 5x5 grid with light internal boarders and dark outside boarders and then use copy and paste (format) to effectively double the size each time.  Wouldn't take long to have a grid as big as you could need.

Unless you wanted to go the vba route...